# After reading a file, and (with append function) puting it into a file again, a lot of '\n' 's appear

Tags: c++, text

**Basically, i loadup text files, and put them into another text file, but when outputing, when it should look something like this:**

Nuskaityti krepsininku duomenys:
komanda    vardas    pavarde    gimimo m.    ugis    pozicija    taskai    klaidos

---

kom1       var1      pav1       1985         189     gynejas     10        5
kom2       var2      pav2       1955         159     vidurys     7         2
kom3       var3      pav3       1999         162     gynejas     5         5
kom2       var4      pav4       1956         157     puolejas    5         3
kom1       var5      pav5       1986         185     gynejas     10        4
kom5       var6      pav6       1959         165     vidurys     21        3
kom3       var7      pav7       1992         192     puolejas    5         4

---

**looks like this**

Nuskaityti krepsininku duomenys:

(\n(not in the code, just for showing purpose))

komanda    vardas    pavarde    gimimo m.    ugis    pozicija    taskai    klaidos

---

kom1       var1      pav1       1985         189     gynejas     10        5

kom2       var2      pav2       1955         159     vidurys     7         2

kom3       var3      pav3       1999         162     gynejas     5         5

kom2       var4      pav4       1956         157     puolejas    5         3

kom1       var5      pav5       1986         185     gynejas     10        4

kom5       var6      pav6       1959         165     vidurys     21        3

kom3       var7      pav7       1992         192     puolejas    5         4

---

i use this to move the info from txt files

```
ofstream fout("abc.txt", fstream::app);


String^ str = "R3b.txt";
         StreamReader ^strm = gcnew StreamReader(str);
         String ^ST1=strm->ReadToEnd();
         strm->Close();
         string st1 = marshal_as<string,String ^>(ST1);
         richTextBox1->Text+=ST1;
         fout << st1;


fout.close();
```

i'm thinking that it just takes every new line from the text file and just reads every \n but i cannot think of a way to fix this

Comment: That certainly isn't C++. Looks like C++-cli, C++-cx or whatever those were called.

Comment: You need to open in a binary editor and see *exactly* what characters you have near the end of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, there is a blank being inserted between each line. If that's the case, I'm guessing that you're using windows, and windows stores newlines as `\r\n` which is probably being put back as two newlines, hence the blank line.